# How to count all posts from a CPT?

Tags: wordpress, count

My wordpress real estate theme have a custom post type for properties.

Statuses in backend: All, Mine, Published, Draft, Disabled by user

I have a custom field (prop) and I am trying to autocomplete it when a new post is published.
Wordpress id counting is not ascending by 1. So I want to use that field to autocomplete it with (no of posts + 1)

I have this function.

```
/**   Generate Custom ID when a new Estate Property is published.*/
add_action('publish_estate_property','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id){
    global $post; 
    $no_of_posts = wp_count_posts("estate_property");
    if(get_post_meta($post_id, "prop", true) == "" && !wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
            
        $_POST["prop"] = ($no_of_posts->publish + $no_of_posts->draft + 1);
}
```

I tried

```
$_POST["prop"] = ($no_of_posts->publish + $no_of_posts->draft + 1);
```

and the code is working, but I don't know the value for disabled posts > if I disable a post, the count reset by 1 and that post doesn't count to it.

I was thinking on 2 solutions:

1. How can I count all statuses?
2. How can I get last value and add +1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution atm is

```
$_POST["mls"] = ($no_of_posts->publish + $no_of_posts->draft + $no_of_posts->disabled);
```

I was testing with 'disable' before (without **d**).

But still looking for a way to have the value from last post +1 (if user delete posts the count changes)

Answer (score 0):

You could just count all statuses for that post type using a SQL query like so:

```
global $wpdb;


$posts_count = $wpdb->prepare(
    $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'estate_property'"
    )
);
```

Comment: Can I count without specify the statuses? because I don't know the status for Disabled by user

Comment: Yes you can just remove the post_status where clause. I've updated my answer

Comment: Hi again. Any idea how to get the value from last post for that field?

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ($post_type === 'estate_property') {
        $no_of_posts = wp_count_posts('estate_property');
        if (get_post_meta($post_id, 'prop', true) === '' && !wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
            $_POST['prop'] = $no_of_posts->publish + $no_of_posts->draft + 1;
        }
    }
}
```